# Limit of a multivariable function, with numerator to the power of 3

Tags: limits

> Define $f(x,y)=\dfrac{(x+y)^3}{x^2+y^2}$ for all $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$.
>
> Calculate $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} f(x,y)$ if this limit exists, or prove that this limit does not exist.

I tried replacing the value of $0$ to first $x$ and then $y$, and I get respectively $x$ and $y$ as results. Does that mean that the limit doesn't exist?

Also, how would you use polar coordinates here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way:
\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{(x+y)^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right|&\leq\dfrac{(|x|+|y|)^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\\
&\leq\dfrac{(\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}+\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}})^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\\
&=8\cdot\dfrac{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{3/2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\\
&=8\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}\\
&\rightarrow 0.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Squaring AM-QM or Cauchy-Schwarz you get

- $(x+y)^2\leq 2(x^2+y^2)$

So, you have

$$\left|\dfrac{(x+y)^3}{x^2+y^2}\right| = |x+y|\frac{(x+y)^2}{x^2+y^2}$$ $$\leq |x+y|\frac{2(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2} = 2|x+y|\stackrel{(x,y)\to (0,0)}{\rightarrow} 0$$

Answer (score 0):

By polar coordinates we have

$$\frac{(x+y)^3}{x^2+y^2}=r(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)^3\to0$$

Comment: The method I used gives 0 for both x and y. So is it correct as well?

Comment: But more importantly, could you explain why do you get zero as result?

Comment: @youser202342 Taking $x=0$ or $ y=0$ or $y=mx$ doesn't guarantee that the limit is equal to zero. There are infinitely many paths, we can't never consider all of them. This way is effective when limit doesn't exists but this is not the case.

Comment: @youser202342 By polar coordinates we can conclude since $r \to 0$ and $(\sin \theta + \cos \theta)$ is bounded. To be rigorous we can use squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Take $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$ so that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{(x+y)^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}} \Rightarrow \lim_{r\to 0} r(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)^{3} = 0$$ So the limit exists and is zero.

Comment: Yeah, the way I did it would result 0 for both cases. Would it be the same then?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you analyzed the cases where $x=0$ and $y=0$,but this is not enough. You have to show that the limit is zero independently of the "path" taken.